# What is the difference between smaps and smaps_rollup in linux

Tags: linux, memory, proc

What is the difference between smaps and smaps_rollup in linux?
I don't know why PSS size is different between the sum of smaps and smaps_rollup in all processes.
I want to know how these commands get a PSS size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Linux kernel calculates PSS (proportional set size), the kernel handles the value in the byte level (in practice, the kernel calculates PSS in much more fine-grained level. See below code snippet.). Here is a code snippet from `smaps_account` in `/fs/proc/task_mmu.c`:

```
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++, page++) {
        int mapcount = page_mapcount(page);
        unsigned long pss = PAGE_SIZE << PSS_SHIFT;
        if (mapcount >= 2)
            pss /= mapcount;
        smaps_page_accumulate(mss, page, PAGE_SIZE, pss, dirty, locked,
                      mapcount < 2);
    }
```

As you can see, to calculate `pss` for each page, the kernel divides the value by `mapcount` of the page before using it. So, the actual value can be represented in the byte-level. For example, if a page is mapped by three processes, each process gets 4KB/3 (1365.333 bytes) of `pss` size for this page.

When users request to print `/proc/<pid>/smaps`, the kernel prints `smaps` for each `vma` in the target process while `/proc/<pid>/smaps_rollup` prints the sum of `smaps`. The problem is, the kernel prints values of `/proc/<pid>/smaps` (and also for `/proc/<pid>/smaps_rollup`) in KB. It means that PSS value under 1KB is discarded. See below code snippet. All printed values are right-shifted by 10.

```
#define SEQ_PUT_DEC(str, val) \
        seq_put_decimal_ull_width(m, str, (val) >> 10, 8)

/* Show the contents common for smaps and smaps_rollup */
static void __show_smap(struct seq_file *m, const struct mem_size_stats *mss,
    bool rollup_mode)
{
    SEQ_PUT_DEC("Rss:            ", mss->resident);
    SEQ_PUT_DEC(" kB\nPss:            ", mss->pss >> PSS_SHIFT);
    SEQ_PUT_DEC(" kB\nPss_Dirty:      ", mss->pss_dirty >> PSS_SHIFT);
    if (rollup_mode) {
        /*
         * These are meaningful only for smaps_rollup, otherwise two of
         * them are zero, and the other one is the same as Pss.
         */
        SEQ_PUT_DEC(" kB\nPss_Anon:       ",
            mss->pss_anon >> PSS_SHIFT);
        SEQ_PUT_DEC(" kB\nPss_File:       ",
            mss->pss_file >> PSS_SHIFT);
        SEQ_PUT_DEC(" kB\nPss_Shmem:      ",
            mss->pss_shmem >> PSS_SHIFT);
    }
//...
```

For `/proc/<pid>/smaps_rollup`, the kernel aggregates values in each `smaps` of `vma` including the discarded value under 1KB, then prints the value in KB. That's why the sum of PSS in `smaps` is differ from the PSS value in `smaps_rollup`.